# The main header has disappeared

Tags: customization

The main header (Save File etc) has disappeared. How do I get it back?

[image]

Comment: Click the upper left icon and select *Info*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also load your file with the default interface. Here is how to do it:

- Quit blender
- Open it again to get the "startup file" and the default interface
- Click "File -> Open..." and uncheck "load UI" before choosing your file

Comment: As a quick note to that, the start-up is it's own .blend file, therefore, can be saved with CTRL + U

Answer (score 4):

All default windows in blender are all customizable, and as you may of noticed, changeable. It appears you have changed the window  on your top bar.

Click the small box, revealing a drop-down.
[image: Outliner tab]

And in the drop-down, select Info.

[image: Info]