# Blender won't open my Template or Not let me edit it

Tags: rendering, interface, export

So im new to Blender but all the templates I have downloaded work after I double click or open with blender.

But this one template for some reason wont show and wont let me edit it(link below) Strange is also that I can indeed render the animation ,ut why cant I edit it?

Link of template:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQhFOy2Dt-s

This is what pops up in blender instead of a normal editing screen:
[image]

Comment: Try hitting **Shift** + **F5** with your mouse over the area you would be expecting a different view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The main header has disappeared](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44254/the-main-header-has-disappeared)

Comment: nope no f5 and shift with mouse hovering

Comment: nope nothing has worked

Answer (score 1):

Following the picture below, in your scene, first click the button at the square labeled **1** and in the popup menu select **3D View**. Then click, hold, and drag the grip at the square labeled **2** and drag up into the bar immediately above it to get rid of the extra toolbar.

[image: How to change]