# My Outliner and Properties editor dissapeared... how do I get them back?

Tags: properties, outliner

Help this keeps happening and I lose my whole projects because of it:
As you can see in this image its not there...[image]

Comment: [Check out this Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44258/15543) of what is most likely a duplicate question to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try shift +F9. Also not sure what you mean by the properties bar. Try clicking “N” if that is the one you need.

Comment: Use `<kbd>F9</kbd>` for keyboard key markup. Hit the edit button on any q / a to see markdown.